# Randomly divide df in list of df into equal subsets

Tags: r, list, random, subsampling

yesterday I already asked a similar question: [R - Randomly split a dataframe in n equal pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288288/r-randomly-split-a-dataframe-in-n-equal-pieces/58295844?noredirect=1#comment102987959_58295844)

The answer I got is nearly what I need, but there are still problems with it. Also I thought about different other ways to get a result.

This is my example df-list:

```
set.seed(0L)
AB_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1624,rep=TRUE)))
BC_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
DE_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
FG_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1729,rep=TRUE)))

AB_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1624,rep=TRUE)))
BC_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
DE_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
FG_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1729,rep=TRUE)))

df_list = list(AB_df, BC_df, DE_df, FG_df, AB_pc, BC_pc, DE_pc, FG_pc)
names(df_list) = c("AB_df", "BC_df", "DE_df", "FG_df", "AB_pc", "BC_pc", "DE_pc", "FG_pc")
```

I want to randomly subset the single df within the list into n equal parts (or as close as possible to equal). I already got a very helpful answer from chinsoon12:

```
new = lapply(df_list, function(df) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  split(df, cut(sample(n), seq(1, n, by=floor(n/4)), labels=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE))})
```

The problem is that its not working for any number of rows and also not all observations are taken in account. E.g. when I devide my df_list in 5 subsets with that methode I am getting subsets of 325, 324, 324, 324, 324 for AB_df and in total thats not 1624, so something is missing. When I devide it into 4 pieces, I only get 3 subsets...any idea why this is happening?

I also thought about 2 different ways of splitting the df in the list. One way might be to just reorder the observations randomly by changing the order of the rows in a random way:

```
for (a in 1:length(df_list)) {
  df_list[[a]] = df_list[[a]][sample(nrow(df_list[[a]])),]}
```

Now I would only need to devide the dfs into n pieces...but this is the point where I am not sure how to do that.

3rd way I thought of would be to create a random list of numbers 1:n for n-subsamples and add them to the dataframes and then extract the df according to the number.

I still think the first way is the easiest and I would prefer this. Any idea whats wrong with the code?

Comment: >When I devide it into 4 pieces, I only get 3 subsets...any idea why this is happening?

This happens because cut literally cuts your values in equal parts on the edges you are telling it to. So giving 4 edges results in 3 intervals.

Comment: Please don’t ask duplicate questions on the same topic — if the first question isn’t answered to your satisfaction it remains active, and you can edit it to provide clarification and details.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. I was really desperate to get an answer. I really try to aviod this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem resulting in your different group-sizes is a cut-thing. It does always need a hard interval-border on one side and I don't really know how to do that in your case.
You could solve your problem with `gl`, just ignore the warnings.
And when you randomize the generated levels before you apply them, you're there.

```r
set.seed(0L)
AB_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1624,rep=TRUE)))
BC_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
DE_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
FG_df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1729,rep=TRUE)))

AB_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1624,rep=TRUE)))
BC_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
DE_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1656,rep=TRUE)))
FG_pc = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,1729,rep=TRUE)))

df_list = list(AB_df, BC_df, DE_df, FG_df, AB_pc, BC_pc, DE_pc, FG_pc)
names(df_list) = c("AB_df", "BC_df", "DE_df", "FG_df", "AB_pc", "BC_pc", "DE_pc", "FG_pc")

#the number of groups you want to generate
subs <- 4

splittedList <-  lapply(df_list,
                        function(df){
                          idx <- gl(n = subs,round(nrow(df)/subs))
                          split(df, sample(idx))# randomize the groups
                        })
#> Warning in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...):
#> data length is not a multiple of split variable

#> Warning in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...):
#> data length is not a multiple of split variable

## the groups are appr. equally sized:
lapply(splittedList,function(l){sapply(l,nrow)})
#> $AB_df
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 406 406 406 406 
#> 
#> $BC_df
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 414 414 414 414 
#> 
#> $DE_df
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 414 414 414 414 
#> 
#> $FG_df
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 432 432 433 432 
#> 
#> $AB_pc
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 406 406 406 406 
#> 
#> $BC_pc
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 414 414 414 414 
#> 
#> $DE_pc
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 414 414 414 414 
#> 
#> $FG_pc
#>   1   2   3   4 
#> 432 432 433 432

## and the sizes are right:
sapply(df_list,nrow)
#> AB_df BC_df DE_df FG_df AB_pc BC_pc DE_pc FG_pc 
#>  1624  1656  1656  1729  1624  1656  1656  1729

sapply(splittedList,function(l){sum(sapply(l,nrow))})
#> AB_df BC_df DE_df FG_df AB_pc BC_pc DE_pc FG_pc 
#>  1624  1656  1656  1729  1624  1656  1656  1729
```